# Prove $\bigcup \{A,B,C\} = (A \cup B) \cup C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

Note: The analogue of this question for intersections is answered here:

> [Prove $\bigcap \{A,B,C\} = (A \cap B) \cap C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486746/prove-bigcap-a-b-c-a-cap-b-cap-c)

This question asks how to prove $\bigcup \{A,B,C\} = (A \cup B) \cup C$. Here is my proof attempt:

\begin{align*}
x \in \bigcup \{A,B,C\}
&\iff \left(\exists X\right) \left(X \in \{A,B,C\} \land x \in X\right) \\
&\iff \left(\exists X\right) \left(X \in \left(\{A,B\} \cup \{C\}\right) \land x \in X\right) \\
& \quad \ \vdots \\
&\iff \left((x \in A) \lor (x \in B)\right) \lor x \in C \\
&\iff x \in (A \cup B) \lor x \in C \\
&\iff x \in (A \cup B) \cup C
\end{align*}

I am not sure what formal logical results in set theory I need to fill in the intermediate steps. Especially the rigorous steps involving when the existential quantifier $\exists$ simplifies away.

Note: I know that $\cup$ is associative so I could have written $(A \cup B) \cup C$ as $A \cup (B \cup C)$, or even as "$A \cup B \cup C$", but I am trying to be as rigorous and formal as possible with logical symbols and punctuation in this proof.

**Update 2015-10-18**: I posted a follow-up question asking how to prove the quantification result mentioned in BrianO's answer:

> [Prove $∀w(∀v((v=w∧φ(v))⇔φ(w)))$](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28837/prove-%E2%88%80w%E2%88%80vv-w%E2%88%A7%CF%86v%E2%87%94%CF%86w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some intermediate step to the conclusion:
\begin{align*}
x \in \bigcup \{A,B,C\}
&\iff \left(\exists X \in \{A,B,C\}\right) x \in X \\
& \quad \ \vdots \\
&\iff \exists X\left( \left(\left( X = A \vee X = B \right) \vee X = C\right) \wedge x \in X \right) \\
&\iff \exists X\left( \left(\left( X = A \vee X = B \right) \wedge x \in X \right) \vee \left(X = C \wedge x \in X \right)\right)\\
&\iff \exists X\left( \left(\left( X = A \wedge x \in X \right) \vee \left(X = B  \wedge x \in X \right)\right) \vee \left(X = C \wedge x \in X \right)\right)\\
&\iff  \left(\exists X\left( X = A \wedge x \in X \right) \vee \exists X\left(X = B  \wedge x \in X \right)\right) \vee \exists X\left(X = C \wedge x \in X \right)\\
&\iff \left((x \in A) \lor (x \in B)\right) \lor x \in C \\
&\iff x \in (A \cup B) \lor x \in C \\
&\iff x \in (A \cup B) \cup C
\end{align*}

This takes a slightly different approach at the beginning.

Here's how/why you can eliminate the existential quantifier.

For a formula $\varphi$, 
$$\forall w \forall v((v=w \wedge \varphi(v)) \implies \varphi(w))$$

is valid and provable: it might as well be an instance of a first-order axiom schema. We assume that $v, w$ are fresh variables that don't get "captured", etc. So $v$ is not free in the consequent $\varphi(w)$, thus we can move the $v$ quantifier inside, to govern only the antecedent:
$$\forall w (\exists v(v=w \wedge \varphi(v)) \implies \varphi(w))$$

So for any constant or term $t$, 
$$\exists v(v=t \wedge \varphi(v))⟹\varphi(t)$$
is valid and provable.

In your problem, $\varphi(v)$ is $x \in v$; you'd be taking $t$ to be $A,B,C$ in turn.

**Or** do it without all the formal fuss, and show that both expressions denote the same set.

Comment: Awesome! I much prefer the "formal fuss" ;) Thank you!

Comment: How do we get rid of the $\exists X$ about three lines from the bottom? Is there a result or theorem in logic that allows us to perform this action?

Comment: You're welcome :) When you're learning this material it's good to work out the gory details. Eventually you'll just know at a glance what they are, and then you can "hand-wave" with confidence.

Comment: For any $c$,  $\exists v( v = c \wedge \varphi(v)) \implies \varphi(c)$ is valide and provable. Here's why:
$\forall w \forall v( ( v = w \wedge \varphi(v)) \implies \varphi(w))$  is valid, might as well be an instance of a first-order axiom schema. We assume that $v$ not free in $\varphi(w)$, etc -- it's a fresh variable. Therefore we can move the $v$ quantifier inside, to apply to the antecedent only; the sentence becomes 
 $\forall w ( \exists v( x = w \wedge \varphi(v)) \implies \varphi(w))$.

 Here, you'd be instantiating with $A, B, C$ for $w$, and $\varphi(v)$ is $x \in v$.

Comment: Great! Should that comment read $\implies$ or $\iff$? Also, do you have a good reference book for this?

Comment: In the first formula/sentence involving $c$, yes $\iff$ works too. I'd think any of a few good books on first order logic would do the trick, especially one that paid a lot of attention to actually using the rules of deduction. Though I haven't seen recent editions (it's gone through many, currently at the 14th), Irving Copi "Introduction to Logic" formerly titled "Symbolic Logic" or something, would be a good source. It's crazy expensive now, of course, but really any edition would do and you can probably find early ed.s for near-free. Elliot Mendelson's "Introduction to Mathematical Logic".

Comment: I expanded the answer to include the remarks from three comments back about eliminating $\exists$.

Comment: Thanks again @BrianO! Just wanted to let you know I posted a follow up question in case you're interested (see link added to original question).

Answer (score 0):

To do any proofs, you have to define notation first. I would think that you define
$$
\bigcup \{A,B,C\} = \{x | x \in A \text{ or } x \in B \text{ or } x \in C\}
$$

So now, $x \in \bigcup \{A,B,C\}$ implies $x\in A$ or $x\n B$ or $x \in C$, which in turn implies $x \in A \cup B$ or $x \in C$, i.e. $x \in (A \cup B) \cup C$.

Can you go the other way?

Comment: $\bigcup \{A,B,C\}$ is defined formally as  $x\in\bigcup\{A,B,C\} \iff (\exists X)(X\in \{A,B,C\}\land x\in X)$